# Entity Framework Code First Mapping Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to create a model on an existing database.

I currently have the following entity mappings:

```
public class TripDriverMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<TripDriver>
{
    public TripDriverMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.TripDriverMapID);

        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("slx_TripDriverMap");
        this.Property(t => t.TripDriverMapID).HasColumnName("TripDriverMapID");
        ...
        this.Property(t => t.DriverID).HasColumnName("EntityID");

        // Relationships
        ...
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Driver)
            .WithMany(t => t.TripDrivers)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DriverID);
        ...
    }
}

public class DriverMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Driver>
{
    public DriverMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        ...

        this.Property(t => t.ID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.OwnerEntityID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("slx_vw_Drivers");
        ...
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("EntityID");
        ...
    }
}
```

If you look closely I have a column called **EntityID** which I have mapped to the property **DriverID**. Whenever I try to include related entities from either side I get the following error:

Invalid column name 'EntityPerson_EntityPersonID'.

This is caused because part of the SQL being generated is as follows:

```
[Extent1].[EntityPerson_EntityPersonID] AS [EntityPerson_EntityPersonID]
FROM  [dbo].[slx_TripDriverMap] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[slx_vw_Drivers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[EntityID] = [Extent2].[EntityID]
```

As you can see it is looking for a column called **EntityPerson_EntityPersonID** which doesn't exist. **It does join on the correct columns**

I cannot rename the column in the TripDriverMap table as it is in use in far to many places, both in the database, the application, and reports.

How can I get this to work? I've done all that I thought I had to do in the **TripDriverMap** mapping definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a property defined on another class EntityPerson which had a collection of TripDriver objects. When I removed that collection as it was no longer needed the SQL generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying your TripDrive-Driver relationship like this

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Driver)
        .WithMany(t => t.TripDrivers)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.DriverID);
```

try explicitly defining the foreign key name

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.Driver)
        .WithMany(t => t.TripDrivers)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("EntityPersonID"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work - I got an error saying that the property already was defined.

Comment: Did you remove the `this.Property` declaration for `DriverID` when you added the `HasRequired` with `Map`?  Otherwise that error would be correct.